# Will all messages ever from a thread be retrieved, or only the ones after truncation

Tags: openai-api

Per the official documentation:

> There is no limit to the number of Messages you can store in a Thread. Once the size of the Messages exceeds the context window of the model, the Thread will attempt to include as many messages as possible that fit in the context window and drop the oldest messages.

I understand that the number of messages given to the assistant will be truncated to fit the context window.

It's not clear to me that if I retrieve all the messages from a thread with the following api, will it gives me the full message list or the truncated list (assuming we went out of the context window). I know the api only gives 100 messages per request, and you have to make multiple requests using the `after` parameter to get the full list.

`GET https://api.openai.com/v1/threads/{thread_id}/messages`